# query processing (natural join)

Tags: database

i need little help
please answer this question anyone
Consider a join of 3 relations:
r natural join s natural join t

Since join is commutative and associative, the system could join r and s first, s and t first, or r and t first, and then join the remaining relation with the result. If the system is able accurately to estimate. How large the result of a join will be without actually computing the join, should it choose first

1.the join with the largest result
2.the join with the smallest result.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the join with the smallest result set allows you to reduce the amount of work to be done in the future.

Consider the case where you joing 10 relations with 1.000.000 elements each, knowing that each join will produce on the order of (10^6)^2 elements, and then join with a relation with 10 elements (knowing that result will be 10 elements only). Compare this to a case where you start with 10-element relation first.

Comment: so the best method is to join relations with smallest results first. right?
and can you please provide any other strong reasoning of this action?

Comment: can you provide some other reason for this action. actually this is one of my assignment questions

Comment: Compare "take social_security data, join with addresses on name, join with phone numbers on name, join with my_brothers on name" (where my_brothers has 1 element) vs "take my_brothers, join with addresses on name, join with phone numbers on name, join with social_security on name" - which will be more efficient? When looking something up in the phonebook and then on the map, will you start by looking a specific entry in phonebook, and then its address on map, or will you join phonebook with map first, and then join with the name that you know?